# call server side function from gridview in a html control

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview.There is a Itemtemplete inside that. In itemtemplete I have a `<th>` which should be conditionally visible or hidden. I want to call a server side function for calculating that condition.

I am getting error on this line

```
<th align="left" <%# String.Format("getDisplay(Eval('QuestionId'))") %> runat="server" id="chkTh">
```

How to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
protected void OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
<th align="left"  style="<%# getDisplay(Convert.ToString(Eval('QuestionId'))) %>" runat="server" id="chkTh">

    public string getDisplay(string QuestionId)
    {
          //check for the visibility over here and return "display:none;" if you want to hide
    }
```